# About Jquery + Metamask + Web3.js

Tags: web3js, metamask, jquery

How to write an Ethereum APPROVE authorization script function with Jquery, so that the user clicks the authorization button on the website, and the website has the right to obtain the corresponding token transfer rights of the user in the ERC20 system?

Comment: Did you try calling approve from the contract with the right addresses?

Comment: Hello, how can I use the JQUERY code to achieve it？

Comment: I'd recommend to use a library like ethers.js or web3.js to interact with contracts.